# Use a custom ClassDecorator to inject a dependency in class instance

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typescript-decorator, reflect-metadata

I'm writing a module for NestJS where I'd like to have a custom `ClassDecorator` that:

- Makes a class `@Injectable`
- Injects a dependency in the class instance

Here is a few lines of code that illustrate what I expect:

```js
// app.module.ts

@Module({
  providers: [AppService, MyClass]
})
export class AppModule {}

// my-class.ts

@MyClassDecorator(AppService)
export class MyClass {}

// Somewhere else where MyClass is injected as `myclass`
console.log(myclass)
// MyClass { injectedThroughDecorator: AppService {} }
```

I've googled for a lot of reference on how to implement custom decorators and I think I'm good with this. I've also started to read some documentations about `reflect-metadata` as I think reflection could help me achieve this.

The next step is to define a method decorator that would have access to the `AppService` instance injected with `MyClassDecorator`.

For example, let's say that `AppService` is implemented as an `EventEmitter`:

```js
@MyClassDecorator(AppService)
export class MyClass {

    @MyMethodDecorator('event')
    myDecoratedFunction(eventName: string, data: any) {
        console.log(`Hi there! I've been triggered by the AppService's ${eventName} event with ${data}`);
    }

}
```

Do you have any advice on how I should implement such a decorator? Any help/example/reference would be greatly appreciated. Lastly, don't hesitate to ask for more details or explanation on what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks for reading me,
Have a nice day!

Comment: Not clear how `myDecoratedFunction` is going to be invoked and how that relates to `AppService`. Can you give a little more context? A more concrete and complete example would help.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewEisenberg for commenting on this question. I've found a solution but I haven't answered yet. The point was to perform something like `myAppServiceInstance.on('event', myClassInstance.myDecoratedFunction)`
You can see how I implemented this here https://github.com/fwoelffel/nest-bull/blob/dev/lib/bull.explorer.ts